# Filtering child collection with subquery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-query-syntax

I have a query in sql, as shown in the code below:

```
select *
from Registration r
    inner join RegistrationService rs on rs.RegistrationID = r.RegistrationID
    inner join Service s on s.ServiceID = rs.ServiceID
where cast(RegistrationDate as DATE) between @startDate and @endDate
    and s.ByDoctor = 'false'
    and rs.ServiceID not in (select ServiceID from TreatmentService ts where ts.TreatmentID = r.RegistrationID)
```

Now I have to convert this into linq syntax because I'm using EF as my data access. I'm getting a problem when converting the last line:

```
rs.ServiceID not in (select ServiceID from TreatmentService ts where ts.TreatmentID = r.RegistrationID)
```

and my linq syntax:

```
var query = context.Registrations.Where(r =>
    DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.RegistrationDate) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Today)
    &&
    r.RegistrationServices.Any(rs => rs.Service.ByDoctor == false)
    &&
    !(context.TreatmentServices.Select(ts => ts.ServiceID).Where(ts => ts.TreatmentID == r.RegistrationID)).Contains(rs.ServiceID) <-- here is the problem
);
```

How to solve this?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Pikoh I know it's caused by `rs.ServiceID`, but I did not find a way to convert this into linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the linq query-like syntax?

```
from r 
in context.Registration
join rs in context.RegistrationService on rs.RegistrationID = r.RegistrationID
join s in context.Service on  s.ServiceID = rs.ServiceID
...
```

Taken from: [LINQ query examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx#SimpleInnerJoin)

Comment: Why not use the nice navigation properties?

Answer (score 0):

```
from r 
in context.Registration
join rs in context.RegistrationService on rs.RegistrationID equals r.RegistrationID
join s in context.Service on  s.ServiceID  equals  rs.ServiceID

where s.Where(ts=>ts.TreatmentID == r.RegistrationID).All(ts => ts.ServiceID  != rs.ServiceID )
```